# Works on emulator and test but not on alpha test in google store

Tags: java, android

Have an app works perfectly on an emulator or my test phone, but when downloaded from google store keep getting a null pointer.   The server either returns a "1" or "0", any idea what's wrong?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mobile.donswholesale.Scan$7.onPostExecute(Scan.java:363)
at com.mobile.donswholesale.Scan$7.onPostExecute(Scan.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here's line 363:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            ///This is line 363:
            if (result.trim().equals("1")) {
                Toast.makeText(Scan.this,
                            getString(R.string.vin_exists), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

            } else {
                StartBid();
            }
            }

    }.execute();

}
```

And here's the php that checks if a VIN exists:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($VINexists) > 0) {

echo ("1");
}else{
echo ("0");
}
```

Comment: well it worked fine yesterday and this morning has crapped out, nothing changed, emulator with the exact same code still works flawlessly.

Comment: I have it posting the result in DDMS, always a "1" or a "0"...it's never null.

Comment: Well I figured this out, it is because I am inside our network.  Kill wifi on the phone and it works without any problems.  Any suggestions on handling this?  I want to be able to hit our server inside or outside the lan regardless of if the phone has joined the wifi or not.

Comment: to less details about your environment, but never the less put a `if (result == null)` in the beginning of your method to avoid the `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is occuring because the phone is inside the LAN and trying to hit the external server IP address.